# Display cell in new table based on data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set of information with column header as "Description" (range A:A) and row header as "Name" (range 1:1).

**Description**--------**John**--------**Mike**
Apple-------------0 or blank--------5
Oranges---------------10------------6
Pear---------------------5-------------9

I would like to populate/display these data into a personalized table for each individual.

**Name:** John
**No.**-------------------------**Description**
1--------------(this should reflect 'Orange' as Apple is blank)
2--------------(this should reflect 'Pear')

**Name:** Mike
**No.**-------------------------**Description**
1--------------(this should reflect 'Apple' as Apple is NOT blank)
2--------------(this should reflect 'Oranges')
3--------------(this should reflect 'Pear')

<[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkbmy.png)>

How do i populate the data set into the personalized table in such a way that item number 1 will always be the description for the first item that is not empty/blank (or 0)?

I have tried and error with Index and Match functions, however to no avail.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$4)/(INDEX($B$2:$C$4, 0, MATCH($E$9, $B$1:$C$1, 0))<>0), D12)), TEXT(,))
```

[image]